# Subtraction of two values

Tags: javascript, subtraction

need to subtract `simpleCart_total` with `&_SESSION['usr']['points']` to get a final total.
Basically javascript value subtract from a database value.

Any ideas how this can be done?

```
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td class='odd'><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['usr']['usr'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');    ?></td>
<td class='even'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='odd'>Your Value Points: </td>
<td class='even'><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['usr']['points'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='odd'>&nbsp;</td>
<td class='even'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='odd'>Total Items: </td><td class='even'><span class='simpleCart_quantity'></span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='odd'>SubTotal: </td><td class='even'><span class='simpleCart_total'></span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='odd'>&nbsp;</td>
<td class='even'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='odd'>Total</td>
<td class='even'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where do you get the simpleCart_quantity value?

Comment: The simpleCart_quantity and simpleCart_total is from javascript, if you click on a product, the value changes recordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I just add an id to the row where put user points, added an id to simpleCart_total and an id to the total result 
    
        
        
         
        
        
        Your Value Points:

```
    <tr><td class='odd'>Total Items: </td><td class='even'><span id='simpleCart_quantity' class='simpleCart_quantity'></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td class='odd'>SubTotal: </td><td class='even'><span id='simpleCart_total' class='simpleCart_total'>4</span></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='odd'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class='even'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='odd'>Total</td>
    <td class='even' id="total">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

And then you call this function everytime you add or remove an item:

```
<script>
function total(){
    var points =  parseFloat(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);
    var simpleCart_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('simpleCart_total').innerHTML);

    var total = document.getElementById('total');

    total.innerHTML = points-simpleCart_total;

}
</script>
```

EDIT

I dont know if it will work, but you can try.
Backup your file javascript/cart.js, and then find and substitute this code:

```
for(var c=0;a.childNodes[c];c++){var d=a.childNodes[c];if(d.className&&d.className.match(/item_[^ ]+/)){var e=/item_[^ ]+/.exec(d.className)[0].split("_");if(e[1]=="add"||e[1]=="Add"){var f=[];f.push(d);var g=simpleCart.Shelf.addToCart(b.id);simpleCart.addEventToArray(f,g,"click");d.id=b.id}else{b[e[1]]=d}}
```

for this:

```
for(var c=0;a.childNodes[c];c++){var d=a.childNodes[c];if(d.className&&d.className.match(/item_[^ ]+/)){var e=/item_[^ ]+/.exec(d.className)[0].split("_");if(e[1]=="add"||e[1]=="Add"){var f=[];f.push(d);var g=simpleCart.Shelf.addToCart(b.id);simpleCart.addEventToArray(f,g,"click");d.id=b.id}else{b[e[1]]=d}}var points=parseFloat(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);var simpleCart_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('simpleCart_total').innerHTML);var total=document.getElementById('total');total.innerHTML=points-simpleCart_total;
```

Don't forget to add the id 'total' to the cell where you want to show the result

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still not working like I want it. Please if you have time, go have a look at http://hiteksecurity.net/Demo3/valueshop/index.php and use the username demo and password f2130c. At the bottom it should subtract the user points from product(s) selected and give a number at the total.